# Best way for update object with Nested schema

Tags: python, flask, serialization, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have two model: `ArticleModel` and `TagModel` and `May-To-Many` relation between them.
I'm use `marshmallow` for [de]serializtion.

I want update or create `ArticleModel` instance and I want get from `front-end` following data

```
{
  'title': 'article',
  'tags': [1, 2, 4] // ids of TagModel instances
}
```

I desided it

**schemas**

```
class ArticlePutPostSchema(Schema):
    tags = fields.List(fields.String())
```

**view**

```
def post(self):
    json_data = request.get_json()
    data = ArticlePutPostSchema().load(data=json_data, partial=True)
    data["tags"] = list(
        TagModel.query.filter(TagModel.id.in_(data["tags"]))
    )
    article = ArticleModel(**data)
    db.session.add(article)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(), 200
```

But I think, that its bad way.

Also I tried to apply a [`Pluck`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/nesting.html#specifying-which-fields-to-nest) field

```
Pluck(TagSchema, 'id', many=True)
```

And I got `[{'id': 1, 'id': 2, 'id': 4}]`.

It's also a bad way.

How can to solve it?

Comment: `return jsonify(), 200` <- that can't possibly be what you're testing with?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this is to define a nested schema in ArticlePutPostSchema as described [here](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nesting.html).

```
class TagModelSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.String()

class ArticlePutPostSchema(Schema):
    tags = fields.List(fields.Nested(TagModelSchema))
```

With the nested schema your `data['tags']` should look like this:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'foo'}, {id: 2, name: 'bar'}, ... ]
```

So you don't have to query TagModel anymore.

Maybe you have to refactor your ArticleModel an TagModel for this to work as expected. I.e. you need a [db.relationship()](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#many-to-many-relationships) between the two classes.

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`